# Setting the cursor between two quotes

Tags: javascript

I have this textarea that when I click a link, 2 double quote marks are been inserted:

```
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Comment..."></textarea>
<div id="insert">
 <a href="javascript:;" title='""'>QUOTES</a>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#insert a').click(function () {
   var smiley = $(this).attr('title');
   ins2pos(smiley, 'comment');
});

function ins2pos(str, id) {
   var TextArea = document.getElementById(id);
   var val = TextArea.value;
   var before = val.substring(0, TextArea.selectionStart);
   var after = val.substring(TextArea.selectionEnd, val.length);

   TextArea.value = before + str + after;
   setCursor(TextArea, before.length + str.length);

}

function setCursor(elem, pos) {
   if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
      elem.focus();
      elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
   } else if (elem.createTextRange) {
      var range = elem.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      var posr = pos - 1;
      range.moveEnd('character', posr);
      range.moveStart('character', posr);
      range.select();
   }
}
</script>
```

When the QUOTE link is been clicked the cursor goes after the last character in the textarea like this `""|` but I want the cursor to be in between the 2 quote marks something like this `"|"`

Comment: Maybe do `setCursor(TextArea, before.length + str.length - 1);`?

Comment: thanks Halcyon, it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution

```
setCursor(TextArea, before.length + str.length - 1);
```